# I can't put a listener to hamburger button and the right buttons clicks in a Floating Search View using Ari Morty library

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, searchview

I'm a beginner, I'm trying to implement Floating Search View from this library: [Floating Search View](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview)

I need to connect this hamburger button to my drawer view and the right buttons with actions.

> Listen to hamburger button clicks:

```
mSearchView.setOnLeftMenuClickListener(
        new FloatingSearchView.OnLeftMenuClickListener() { ...} );
```

> To quickly connect your NavigationDrawer to the hamburger button:

```
mSearchView.attachNavigationDrawerToMenuButton(mDrawerLayout);
```

> Listen for item selections

```
   mSearchView.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new FloatingSearchView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onMenuItemSelected(MenuItem item) {                  

      }
   });
```

There are examples but when I put it on my code, bring me an error. Maybe the problem is that I don't know where should be write it.

Please, help me, I have been searching and trying for weeks.

[image]

Comment: Are trying to implement that behavior or you just using that library?

Comment: Also post the error you are getting

Comment: I write  that literaly (the examples) but I don't know where o how to make that work, that's the error.

Comment: How did you add mentioned library to your project?

Comment: I followed the steps that are in the git repository: "In your dependencies, add:
     compile 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:2.1.1'"

Comment: I have edited out the [android-studio] tag from your post. That tag is for questions specifically about using Android Studio, not for Android programming in general. When adding tags, there should be a popup with short descriptions of the proposed tags, and it's good form to read those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is complete example:

`AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.j2ko.webviewapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".FloatingSearchActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

`FloatingSearchActivity` layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.j2ko.webviewapp.FloatingSearchActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_floating_search">

        <com.arlib.floatingsearchview.FloatingSearchView
            android:id="@+id/floating_search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginLeft="10dp"
            app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginTop="10dp"
            app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginRight="10dp"
            app:floatingSearch_searchHint="Search..."
            app:floatingSearch_suggestionsListAnimDuration="250"
            app:floatingSearch_showSearchKey="false"
            app:floatingSearch_leftActionMode="showHamburger"
            app:floatingSearch_close_search_on_keyboard_dismiss="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#c46ec4">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drower item 1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drower item 2"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Drower item 3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And finally `FloatingSearchActivity` :

```
package com.j2ko.webviewapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.arlib.floatingsearchview.FloatingSearchView;
import com.arlib.floatingsearchview.suggestions.model.SearchSuggestion;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FloatingSearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FloatingSearchView mSearchView;
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    //Dummy data for search suggestions
    private static final List<String> SOME_HARDCODED_DATA;
    static {
        SOME_HARDCODED_DATA = new ArrayList<>();
        SOME_HARDCODED_DATA.add("One");
        SOME_HARDCODED_DATA.add("Two");
        SOME_HARDCODED_DATA.add("Three");
        SOME_HARDCODED_DATA.add("Four");
    }

    //This just for illustration how to populate suggestions
    private static class SimpleSuggestions implements SearchSuggestion {
        private final String mData;
        public SimpleSuggestions(String string) {
            mData = string;
        }
        @Override
        public String getBody() {
            return mData;
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(mData);
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<SimpleSuggestions> CREATOR
                = new Parcelable.Creator<SimpleSuggestions>() {
            public SimpleSuggestions createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new SimpleSuggestions(in);
            }

            public SimpleSuggestions[] newArray(int size) {
                return new SimpleSuggestions[size];
            }
        };

        private SimpleSuggestions(Parcel in) {
            mData = in.readString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_floating_search);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mSearchView = (FloatingSearchView) findViewById(R.id.floating_search_view);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryChangeListener(new FloatingSearchView.OnQueryChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSearchTextChanged(String oldQuery, final String newQuery) {
                List<SearchSuggestion> list = new ArrayList<SearchSuggestion>();
                //emulating search on dummy data
                for (String item : SOME_HARDCODED_DATA) {
                    if (item.contains(newQuery)) {
                        list.add(new SimpleSuggestions(item));
                    }
                }
                mSearchView.swapSuggestions(list);
            }
        });

        //now search view controlling drawer open/closer
        mSearchView.attachNavigationDrawerToMenuButton(mDrawerLayout);
    }

}
```

The result is following :

[image]  [image]

Comment: Thanks!!! You are the best!!!! It works perfectly, thank you very much.